# bitcoind JSON-RPC interface timeouts under unit tests

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, python

I am running unit tests against bitcoind which do JSON-RPC requests in high rate. Random failures are an issue. E.g. if you have something like this in printconsole logs:

```
ThreadRPCServer method=gettransaction
ThreadRPCServer method=gettransaction
ThreadRPCServer method=gettransaction
ThreadRPCServer method=gettransaction
....
ThreadRPCServer method=gettransaction
ThreadRPCServer method=gettransaction
sending: inv (37 bytes)
ThreadRPCServer method=gettransaction
ThreadRPCServer method=listtransactions
sending: inv (37 bytes)
```

You start getting:

```
synced with network?".format(name)) from e
cryptoassets.core.backend.bitcoind.BitcoindJSONError: Got timeout when doing bitcoin RPC call listtransactions.
```

I have tried with both reusing HTTP connection and not reusing HTTP connection with various results.

Are there any low hanging fruits to make `bitcoind` RPC interface more stable (increase threads, concurrency, etc.?)

I am using the following Python JSON-RPC implementation:

https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc/blob/master/bitcoinrpc/authproxy.py

UPDATE: Looks like the problematic call might be `listtransactions`. When called at the same the time from command line using `curl` there is no response either:

```
[~]% curl --user foo:bar --data-binary '{"id":"t0", "method": "listtransactions", "params": ["cryptoassets"] }' http://127.0.0.1:8332/ |python -m json.tool
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--100    70    0     0  100    70      0     58
```

Comment: `rpcthreads=64` seems to work around the issue, but doesn't explain what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

I used [**BitcoinLib**](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib) to perform 15,000 consecutive `listtransactions` calls and the result was:

```
0 timeouts
Fastest response: 0.1133479 sec
Slowest response: 0.6475277 sec
```

`bitcoind` was started with the default parameters and was receiving blocks during the test.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll keep digging what causes bitcoind to go haywire. I'll try to make a bash script to repeat the problem. Maybe it's the pattern of calls made.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa here's the gist for the above test: https://gist.github.com/GeorgeKimionis/7532fe23a5ad74c9c628

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes. Stopped using Bitcoin seven years ago. I suggest you explore some modern blockchains.